# Example of forum in Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop, forum

I'm trying to learn to use PHP with an object oriented scheme. I think I understand the concept but I need real example, a forum exactly (the closest to what I want to do).

I know PhpBB but it's maybe too complicated to fully understand it so I'm looking for something simpler but still in object oriented.

Do you know any ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at http://mybboard.net, http://yabbforum.com, or http://simplemachines.org?

Comment: Not yet (I'll) but it seems to me they are already a bit too evolved. As I said to BobRoss, it's too understand how it works so I need something basic without too much functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) http://vanillaforums.org/, has a really nice api, especially V2, currently in development. Uses MVC. It is also the lightest forum I know.

With that said, you might want to read a book on this subject as well [this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90924/what-is-the-best-php-programming-book) has some nice lists.

Comment: thank you I'll look at it. Concerning the book I'm already reading the one proposed in the post you mention (PHP object patterns and practice)

Answer (score 1):

To learn such things, there's nothing better suited as a real project. I'd suggest you look at an object oriented framework ([Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) maybe) and try to write your own small forum (that requires much more than only objects but database access and user management and... - most of that comes built in the framework).

Comment: thank you but the idea is to adapt an existing project (with user management and a kind of small forum) into object oriented. I wanted to have a look at existing project to see how pros do.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that really made OOP click for me was working with data access. Write an abstract data access class (DAO) that encapsulates your most common read/write methods (select, selectByID, selectWhere etc). You'll find it useful and easy to expand on, and a good starting point for any data dependent code (like a forum)